# Steps to handle renaming runtime api + upgrade

Tags: runtime-upgrade, runtime-api, versioning, client

I'm considering a large refactor in our substrate codebase which would involve moving large chunks of code around. This includes a runtime api. In it's destined place, the runtime api's name(both its trait and function name) is misleading contextually, and would need to be changed. This will make the upgrade process tricky, as the runtime api is called consistently by the client.

I'm curious. How are teams dealing with this? Any tricks? Our initial thoughts are around keeping the old, poorly named runtime api around for compatibility until we can do a second release and remove it.